# GGplot order legend using last values on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have some time series data plotted using `ggplot`. I'd like the legend, which appears to the right of the plot, to be in the same order as the line on the most recent date/value on the plot's x-axis. I tried using the `case_when` function, but I'm obviously using it wrong. Here is an example.

```
df <- tibble(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z = runif(100),
  year = sample(seq(1900, 2010, 10), 100, T)
) %>%
  gather(variable, value,-year) %>%
  group_by(year, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value))



df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Example]

```
## does not work

df %>%
  mutate(variable = fct_reorder(variable, case_when(mean ~ year == 2010)))
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may add one extra line

```
ungroup() %>% mutate(variable = fct_reorder(variable, mean, tail, n = 1, .desc = TRUE))
```

before plotting, or use

```
df %>%
  mutate(variable = fct_reorder(variable, mean, tail, n = 1, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

In this way we look at the last values of `mean` and reorder `variable` accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way without adding a new column using `fct_reorder2()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, color = fct_reorder2(variable, year, mean))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "variable")
```

[image]

Although it's not recommendable in your case, to order the legend based on the first (earliest) values in your plot you can set

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, color = fct_reorder2(variable, year, mean, .fun = first2))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "variable")
```

[image]

The default is `.fun = last2` (see also https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html)